# IF statement always evaluates to true

Tags: bash

I have the following snippet, where the function `test` echoes `false`. I use the echoed value in an `if` statement with shell substitution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

test () {
    echo "false"
}

if [[ "$(test)" -eq "true" ]]
then
    echo hello world
fi
```

I would expect to above to *not* print `hello world`, because I assume this would end up saying `[[ "false" -eq "true" ]]`.

However when I run the script it echoes `hello world`.

Comment: `[[ false -eq true ]]` is true, because the strings `false` and `true` both have the same integer value -- of `0` -- unless someone defines a variable by that name with a different value (ie. `false=1`).

Answer (score 0):

If you [read the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test) for `test`, you would realize that the `-eq`, `-gt`, and `-lt` test conditions are only for numeric values.

> INTEGER1 -eq INTEGER2
>       INTEGER1 is equal to INTEGER2

i.e., `if [ 0 -gt 1 ];`

For string comparison in bash, simply use an `=`.

Try using

```
if [[ "$(test)" = "true" ]]
```

This will give you the expected behavior.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
test () {
    echo "false"
}

if [[ "$(test)" = "true" ]]
then
    echo hello world
fi
```